# Urdu language dataset for aspect-based sentiment analysis

Tags: python, dataset, sentiment-analysis, aspect, urdu

[when i run my code i get this error this error because of what>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMVza.png)

```
text_raw_indices = tokenizer.text_to_sequence(text_left + " " + aspect + " " + text_right)
            text_raw_without_aspect_indices = tokenizer.text_to_sequence(text_left + " " + text_right)
            text_left_indices = tokenizer.text_to_sequence(text_left)
            text_left_with_aspect_indices = tokenizer.text_to_sequence(text_left + " " + aspect)
            text_right_indices = tokenizer.text_to_sequence(text_right, reverse=True)
            text_right_with_aspect_indices = tokenizer.text_to_sequence(" " + aspect + " " + text_right, reverse=True)
            aspect_indices = tokenizer.text_to_sequence(aspect)
            left_context_len = np.sum(text_left_indices != 0)
            aspect_len = np.sum(aspect_indices != 0)
            aspect_in_text = torch.tensor([left_context_len.item(), (left_context_len + aspect_len - 1).item()])
            polarity = int(polarity) + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use LASER and you'll be fine. It covers Urdu as well.

You can read more here:

- https://engineering.fb.com/ai-research/laser-multilingual-sentence-embeddings/
- https://github.com/facebookresearch/LASER

There's also unofficial `pypi` package [here](https://pypi.org/project/laserembeddings/). It substitutes some inner dependencies, but still works as expected.

And most important question, so we may better help you: what are you trying to achieve, what is your final goal?

Comment: The funny trick is: you can train the sentiment model on data sets in different languages. Guess english sentiment data would be easier to obtain than urdu one. Once you train it on english set, it'll work for urdu too, as you train model on features from latent space, which covers dozens of languages.